# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python

I am making a sandbox(with sand) and I stumbled on an error in this line:

```
for grain in sand:
            grain.update()
```

The `sand` variable is a dictionary, and I don't know what went wrong. If you need further clarity, comment.
The full program is:

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 360
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
SAND = (194, 178, 128)

GRAVITY = 0.5 # increased gravity

def main_program():
    global sand
    pygame.init()

    game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Sandbox")

    is_crashed = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 32)

    sand_grain = pygame.Surface((4, 4))
    pygame.draw.rect(sand_grain, SAND, (0, 0, 4, 4))

    sand = {}
    sand_id = 0

    while not is_crashed:
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_held = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]

        if mouse_held:
            sand[str(sand_id)] = Grain(mouse_x, mouse_y)
            sand_id += 1
        for grain in sand:
            grain.update()
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                is_crashed = True
            # handle mouse button down event
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # get the position and button of the mouse event
                pos = event.pos
                button = event.button
                # get a list of all grains that are under the mouse cursor
                clicked_grains = [g for g in sand.values() if g.rect.collidepoint(pos)]
                # if there are any grains clicked
                if clicked_grains:
                    # get the topmost grain
                    top_grain = clicked_grains[-1]
                    # if the left mouse button is pressed
                    if button == 1:
                        # set the dragged attribute of the grain to True
                        top_grain.dragged = True
            # handle mouse button up event
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                # get the position and button of the mouse event
                pos = event.pos
                button = event.button
                # get a list of all grains that are under the mouse cursor
                clicked_grains = [g for g in sand.values() if g.rect.collidepoint(pos)]
                # if there are any grains clicked
                if clicked_grains:
                    # get the topmost grain
                    top_grain = clicked_grains[-1]
                    # if the left mouse button is released
                    if button == 1:
                        # set the dragged attribute of the grain to False
                        top_grain.dragged = False
        game_display.fill(WHITE)

        for grain in sand.values():
            grain.draw(game_display, sand_grain)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()

class Grain:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.yv = 0
        self.xv = random.randint(-2, 2) # added horizontal velocity

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 4, 4)
        self.dragged = False # added dragged attribute
    def update(self):
        global sand
        if self.y > HEIGHT - 4: # check for bottom edge collision
            self.y = HEIGHT - 4
            self.yv = 0
        elif self.y < 0: # check for top edge collision
            self.y = 0
            self.yv = 0
        else:
            self.yv += GRAVITY
        if self.x > WIDTH - 4: # check for right edge collision
            self.x = WIDTH - 4
            self.xv = 0
        elif self.x < 0: # check for left edge collision
            self.x = 0
            self.xv = 0
        else:
            self.xv += random.randint(-1, 1) # add some randomness to horizontal movement
        self.x += self.xv
        self.y += self.yv

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 4, 4)

        for other in sand.values(): # check for collisions with other grains
            if other is not self and self.rect.colliderect(other.rect): # use pygame.Rect.colliderect method
                self.yv = 0
                self.xv = 0
                
                if self.y < other.y:
                    self.y = other.y - 4
                elif self.y > other.y:
                    self.y = other.y + 4
                if self.x < other.x:
                    self.x = other.x - 4
                elif self.x > other.x:
                    self.x = other.x + 4
                break
        # check if the grain is being dragged by the mouse
        if self.dragged:
            # get the current mouse position and movement
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            mouse_rel_x, mouse_rel_y = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
            # set the position and velocity of the grain to match the mouse
            self.x = mouse_x
            self.y = mouse_y
            self.xv = mouse_rel_x
            self.yv = mouse_rel_y
            # update the rect of the grain
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 4, 4)
    def draw(self, display, grain):
        display.blit(grain, self.rect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_program()
```

Comment: `for grain in sand` iterates over the keys (which are strings), not the values (which are Grains).  Maybe you meant `for grain in sand.values()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for grain in sand.values():
    grain.update()
```

I think with sand you are accessing the keys and with sand.values you will access the correct instances

Answer (score 2):

it seems that the issue might be caused by the fact that the sand dictionary is not properly initialized before attempting to access its keys.

One possible solution is to move the initialization of the sand dictionary outside of the loop that creates the grains. This way, the dictionary will be properly created before any attempts are made to access its keys.

Another possible solution is to initialize the sand dictionary with empty values before the loop that creates the grains. This way, even if a key is accessed before it has been assigned a value, the dictionary will return a default value (e.g., None) instead of raising a KeyError.

For example, you could modify the while loop as follows:

```
while not is_crashed:
    # Initialize the sand dictionary with empty values
    sand = {str(key): None for key in range(max_num_grains)}

    # Rest of the loop code...
```

Alternatively, you could initialize the sand dictionary with default values (e.g., []) instead of None, depending on the type of values you expect to store in the dictionary.

Comment: The program works until I spawn in the sand. I tried it, and it didn't work at first, but I just changed it up a bit and it works! Are you using chatgpt to generate this?

Comment: i am using custom tool i made that utilizes local llm and RAG on documentation, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for grain in sand.values():
            grain.update()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't accept 2 answers.

Comment: Np. @C1PHER wrote the answer first.